# Laravel JSON response without backslashes

Tags: php, json, laravel

I am using AJAX post data to my controller.

PHP Code:

```
return response()->json($request->root() . '/summer-uploads/' . $store);
```

It returns:

```
"http:\/\/domain.test\/summer-uploads\/summer-uploads\/PGARvUyeXiAbbTOc90b6HGXXf9ZHmqehOA5f25pE.jpeg"
```

As you can see it's adding backslashes, some kind of escaping. How can i remove it, so it would be looking like this:

"http://domain.test/summer-uploads/summer-uploads/PGARvUyeXiAbbTOc90b6HGXXf9ZHmqehOA5f25pE.jpeg"

Comment: [`response()->json(..., 200, [], JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/3929)

Comment: Both worked, guys! Thank you. Also, `return response()->json(data, 200, [], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);` @LawrenceCherone, you forgot the empty array. But i can't see that explained in laravel documentation, where it comes from?

Comment: From here https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Http/JsonResponse.php#L27 though much easyier to find an issue then a solution in the docs with laraval lol

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, indeed. Make an answer, i'll accept it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The docs does not show all the arguments to the json method.

But they are tucked away in the source.

[JsonResponse->__construct():](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Http/JsonResponse.php#L27)

```
/**
 * Constructor.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $data
 * @param  int    $status
 * @param  array  $headers
 * @param  int    $options
 * @return void
 */
 public function __construct($data = null, $status = 200, $headers = [], $options = 0)
 {
     //...
 }
```

The options parameter would be the [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) parameters.

So for example, pretty print and unescaped slashes:

```
response()->json(..., 200, [], JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES|JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Comment: impossible to find that, god. Can we make a note about documentation to Laravel git repository?

Answer (score 5):

If you're using [Eloquent: API Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-resources) you may have a similar problem. The best way to apply json options to your Response or ResponseCollection is:

```php
public function withResponse($request, $response)
{
    $response->setEncodingOptions(JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

patriziotomato's solution worked for laravel just use this.

```
return response()->json([
            'link'=> 'http://somelink.com/something'
          ])->setEncodingOptions(JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Answer (score 1):

try returning it inside a url

```
url('all your path concatenations')
```

in your case

```
return response()->json(url('/summer-uploads/' . $store));
```

Comment: fyi, `url()` doesn't works, it's returns data as without it.

Comment: Interesting, in devtools response it shows backslashes, but ajax success function understands it correctly. Could you explain why?

Comment: Built-in chrome dev tools

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this:

```
return response($jsonData)->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed to return data already present as a JSON string. response()->json() would have forced me to decode the JSON which I didn't want to do.