# Route not getting correct format of url in api

Tags: laravel, rest, api

Im new to Laravel Rest APIs. While trying tutorials I got this error of showing the link to the next route.

```
{  
    "data":{  
        "name":"mollitia",
        "totalPrice":307.44,
        "rating":5,
        "href":{  
            "reviews":"http:\/\/127.0.0.1:8000\/api\/product\/5\/reviews"
        }
    }
}
```

I need to get the href for reviews as,

```
"reviews":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products/5/reviews"
```

**resource**:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Resources\Product;
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\Resource;
class ProductResource extends Resource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'name' => $this->name,
            'totalPrice' => round(( 1 - ($this->discount/100)) * $this->price,2),
            'rating' => $this->reviews->count() > 0 ? round($this->reviews->sum('star')/$this->reviews->count(),2) : 'No rating yet',
            'href' => [
                'reviews' => route('reviews.index',$this->id)
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: How should the URL look?

Comment: @Jonathon it should look like http ://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products/5/reviews

Comment: That's what it looks like you're getting. The only difference I see is the backslashes (\\), before the forward slashes (/), which is expected as it is correct for the JSON format. When whatever it is consumes your API receives your response, it will be decoded into the URL without those backslashes

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I was confused by the backslash and thought its an error.

Comment: No worries. There's probably a way you can make it so that the forward slashes are not escaped with backslashes, but I think the purpose of it is to make the JSON itself more portable in that it can be embedded into HTML/script tags etc. [without causing problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580647/json-why-are-forward-slashes-escaped).

Comment: Ans is already there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50998771/laravel-json-response-without-backslashes